# acCmdSaveRecord does not save record

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a MS Access 2010 application. In a form new records can be entered. Therefore I go to new record on form load:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()    
    DoCmd.GoToRecord Record:=acNewRec
End Sub
```

After information is entered, by click a save button, the record shall be saved and the form shall go to a new record.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```

The code gets executed, however, no new record is created. The input controls are linked to the table fields.

Comment: is your form unbound? silly question really but I had to ask

Comment: I tried it bound and unbound, does not solve the issue.

Comment: are you ensuring that your form is dirty? use an `if dirty then` to ensure theres something to save.

Comment: I enter information into the controls, so there should be something to save. However, how exactly would I use your proposal?

Comment: "The code gets executed, however, no new record is created." -- What exactly happens? Does the record selector still show the "pen" editing icon? If `acCmdSaveRecord` fails, it usually displays an error.

Comment: Yes, pen is displayed. I do not get an any error message.

Comment: Either your code isn't executed (put a MsgBox in `btnSave_Click()` just to be sure), or the button is on a different form than the data. Are there subforms involved? -- `Me.Dirty = False` is much more reliable than `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` in that regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would ensure that the form only attempts a save when it is dirty like below.
I have added an error handler to notify the user that the form cannot be saved.

```
option explicit
private sub btnSave_Click()
on Error goto ErrTrap
if me.dirty= true then
     DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
     DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
end if

ErrTrap:
   MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
end sub
```

there is a work around to avoid the `docmd.runcommand` ; it will save the record... but I have never used it :

```
if me.dirty=true then
   me.dirty=false
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue I just troubleshot; if the form has a textbox with Control Source "Name" it will fail like this without any information. Make sure your table doesn't have a field named "Name"